# Retry an HTTP call in Vert.x N times and then return a Maybe

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have a `Utils.send` method which sends `JsonObject` request over HTTP to a remote destination and receives a result which returns as a `Maybe<JsonObject>` back to the caller.
It can be used as follows:

```
Maybe<JsonObject> response = Utils.send(jsonObjectRequest);
```

This response may be empty (`Maybe.empty()`).

I would like to wrap this method into my custom method which will retry a query (call `send`) N times if the result is empty and return a `Maybe<JsonObject>` which is the result.
The result is empty if the `send` method returns empty after N retries, otherwise, I pass a `Maybe` with a value.

How can I accomplish this in Vert.x/RxJava?

Answer (score 2):

I have a really similar case for which I use following helper class:

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Function;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

public class CustomRepeat implements Function<Flowable<?>, Publisher<?>> {

    private final int retries;
    private int attemptsCount;

    public CustomRepeat(int retries) {
        this.retries = retries;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<?> apply(final Flowable<?> attempts) throws Exception {
        return attempts
            .flatMap((Function<Object, Publisher<?>>) value -> {
                if (attemptsCount < retries) {
                    attemptsCount = attemptsCount + 1;
                    // When this Observable calls onNext, the original
                    // Observable will be retried (i.e. re-subscribed).
                    return Flowable.just(0);
                    // return Flowable.timer(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
                // Max retries hit. Just pass the error along.
                return Flowable.error(new CustomException("Failed to retry"));
            });
    }
}
```

And in your main chain call it like this:

```
Utils.send(jsonObjectRequest)
    .repeatWhen(new CustomRepeat(50))
    .firstElement()
    .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
        if(error instanceof CustomException) {
            return Maybe.empty();
        }
        return Maybe.error(error);
     });
```

Comment: I try it like this:

    Single.just(23)
        .doOnSuccess(i -> logger.info("Emitting {}", i))
        .map(i -> {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("boom %d", i));
        })
        .repeatWhen(new CustomRepeat(5))
        .firstElement()
        .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
          if (error instanceof RuntimeException) {
            return Maybe.empty();
          }
          return Maybe.error(error);
        })
        .subscribe();

00:11:54.333 [main] Emitting 23

Nothing happens, no retry.